# Hibernate cache configuration

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I found next configuration of ehcache in one poject. For me it looks strange and I do not undestand what for A.blist  cache configured. Please help me to understand this configuration.

entity A has list of B type entities

> ```
> <cache name="A.blist"
>        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
>        eternal="false"
>        overflowToDisk="false"
>        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
>
>
> <cache name="B"
>        maxElementsInMemory="5000"
>        eternal="true"
>        overflowToDisk="false"
>        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate caches collections in independent caches. So if you have an entity that has a list or set, it will require it's own cache.

This is explained in the [hibernate - ehcache integration docs](http://ehcache.org/documentation/integrations/hibernate#collections).

Comment: A.blist cache confugures how many collections(instances of list/set etc) may be cached. Conserning current example - this is wrong configuration - there must be more B cached objects then A.blist cached collections